# How to define or name the function F(n) = n + (n-1) + (n-2) ... + 1

Tags: math

I am wondering if there is a mathematical definition or name for below function **F**:

> **F**(n) = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your looking for the [nth triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). However, given that this question has nothing to do with programming, it would be better asked on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Brian Awesome! Many thanks!

Comment: We can resuce it to F(n)=n*(n+1)/2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @HereticMonkeyYou are right! I just run into this function while creating it and am wondering what name should I give it. I will close it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I will close it while it may not be programming strongly related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the sum of integers, it equals `n * (n + 1) / 2`. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: Just reading it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

F(n) is the nth triangle number. It is equal to n(n+1)/2. To see this, rearrange the terms like this:

```
n + 1 + (n-1) + 2 + ... + (n/2+1) + n/2
```

Then there are n/2 pairs of numbers and each pair sums to n + 1: (n/2)(n+1).